# Azure Web App Virtual Application, The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Web Application with Virtual Application configured under the Path mappings section. The virtual path `/SP2019resources` has the Physical Path as `site\wwwroot\SP2019resources`.

[image]

My Azure DevOps pipeline will upload the contents (SharePoint SPPKG files) to this virtual path. And I have already verified that the contents are there, however whenever I formulate a URL as https://{AzureAppName}/SP2019resources/{PackageName}.SP2019.sppkg and open it in the browser the file is not getting downloaded and always getting an error as "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.".

Here is the file view from my web app SCM.

[image]

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time with this issue, I understood what I am missing. Essentially, you will need a `Web.config` file in your virtual application folder to handle the requests.

[image]

The content of the file can be as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <clear />
      <add name="StaticHandler" verb="*" path="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
    </handlers>
    <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

After I add this file to the `/SP2019resources`, the files inside were getting downloaded.

Comment: Yes, it was because of the type of file. Perhaps, you could move web.config file inside nested folder of virtual directory mapped folder otherwise even application with server side pages would be served/execute as static page.


Add the following to a web.config file in the folder containing the files you wish to be served only as static content: